Silverman's book, the arithmetic of elliptic curves, p.399, $E(K)/\hat{\phi}(E'(K))\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$
Let $E: y^2=x^3+Ax^2+Bx, E': y^2=x^3-2Ax^2+(A^2-4B)x$ be elliptic curves over $\Bbb{Q}$.
Let $\phi : E\to E', (x,y)\mapsto (\frac{y^2}{x^2},\frac{ y(B-x^2)}{x^2})$, $O_E,(0,0)\mapsto O_{E'}$.
Let $\phi'$ be its dual isogeny.
From here, let consider the case $A=-6, B=17$, which is an example 4.10 of Silverman's book
Silverman's book 'The arithmetic of elliptic curves'
(http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~lowdimma/BSD/Silverman-Arithmetic_of_EC.pdf).
My question is,
why $\text{dim}_{\Bbb{F}_2}\frac{E(\Bbb{Q})}{\hat{\phi}(E'(\Bbb{Q})[2])}=1$ ?
Let consider a exact sequence
$0\to \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\to E'(\Bbb{Q}) \stackrel{\hat{\phi}}{\to} E(\Bbb{Q}) \to E(K)/\hat{\phi}(E'(\Bbb{Q}))\to 0 $.
$E'/\Bbb{Q}$ and $E/\Bbb{Q}$ are isogenuous, so has the same rank. But this sequence does not simply implies $E(\Bbb{Q})/\hat{\phi}(E'(\Bbb{Q}))\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.
$p.339$ of Silverman's book he uses this result without no explanation.
Therefore, this might be something that can be understood instantly. I think I'm missing some fundamental perspective. If possible, hints would be welcome, so I'd appreciate any comments you might have. Thank you very much in advance

We use the exact sequence (Theorem 4.9) \begin{align*}
0\to \frac{E(\Bbb Q)}{\widehat{\phi}E'(\Bbb Q)}\to \Bbb Q(S, 2)\to \operatorname{WC}(E'/\Bbb Q)[\phi]
\end{align*}
In the paragraph above the claim $E(\Bbb{Q})/\hat{\phi}(E'(\Bbb{Q}))\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ it is computed that the kernel of $\Bbb Q(S, 2)\to \operatorname{WC}(E'/\Bbb Q)[\phi]$ (i.e. the set of $d\in \Bbb Q(S, 2)$ where $C_d$ has a rational point) is precisely $\{1, 17\}\cong \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, so we get the claim from the exact sequence.

Thank you very much! I understand this is a complex, but why it is exact at $\Bbb{Q}(S,2)$ ?

The short exact sequence $0\to E'[\hat \phi]\to E'\to E\to0$ of $G_{\overline K/K}$-modules induces a long exact sequence in group cohomology, part of which is $E'(K)\to H^1(G_{\overline K/K}, E'[\hat\phi])\to H^1(G_{\overline K/K}, E')$. Earlier in X.4 and X.3 it was established that $H^1(G_{\overline K/K}, E'[\hat\phi])\cong K^\times/(K^\times)^2$ and $H^1(G_{\overline K/K}, E')\cong \operatorname{WC}(E'/K)[\phi]$. The map $E'(K)\to H^1(G_{\overline K/K}, E'[\hat\phi])$ actually has its image contained in $K(S, 2)\cong  H^1(G_{\overline K/K}, E'[\hat\phi]; S)$, so we get the exactness
